# OpenGraph Tags are not working for links to our website on Discord

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter, facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

I posted this to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CodingHelp/comments/pqqykt/any_ideas_why_my_og_tags_are_not_working_for_our/) as well asking the same thing.

Here are some picture examples of them working & not working...

[This is posting the links on twitter. You can see 2 links work, 1 does not. The one that does not is a new website I set up. Added the OG Tags 2 hours ago.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdPmM.png)

[This was back on August 7th when I FINALLY got them to work after working on the OG Tags for a month or two.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP10F.png)

[This is today. No matter when I post the links to Discord, they don't work. Also that 3rd link on Twitter on the first image (techblogger.space) does NOT work anywhere.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9TIZ.png)

Here is the code I have on my themes (the code shared is from https://codinghelp.site)

```html
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://codinghelp.site/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://codinghelp.site/bots/codinghelp.png" />

<link type="application/json+oembed" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/oembed.json" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1920" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="1080" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="344214633960049" />


<meta name=”twitter:card” content="summary" /> 
<meta name=”twitter:site” content="https://codingHelp.site" /> 
<meta name=”twitter:title” content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" /> 
<meta name=”twitter:description” content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" /> 
<meta name=”twitter:image” content="https://codinghelp.site/bots/codinghelp.png" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="B58_9jkDcl3NtkMWTZafw4L5cCnFwktp-bVEw6EKt6w" />
```

All 3 websites are running WordPress using Yoast SEO plus, I manually added the OG Tags exactly as shown above. I found this iFramely site and according to it, all of my websites are set up perfectly.
I also have an oembed.json file... this is what is included in that:

```js
{
"title": "CodingHelp",
"author_name": "CodingHelp",
"author_url": "https://codinghelp.site",
"provider_name": "CodingHelp",
"provider_url": "https://codinghelp.site"
}
```

Any ideas why these OG Tags are not working? Also, how long do OG Tags take to update when you first put them on a new site?

Comment: Are they working with Twitter and Facebook? Your tags might be fine, this may be an issue specific to Discord. Opengraph tags take effect immediately when you add them to a fresh website, as the social media site's server makes an on-the-fly request to your page to scrape them. Then, they are usually cached for some period of time on the social media company's server.

Comment: I showed a picture in my post, CodingHelp.site and DudeThatsErin.site work on Twitter & Facebook but not Discord.
Techblogger.space does not work anywhere. I found iFramely (a website to test these tags) and all the tags appear 100% correct on all 3 websites: http://debug.iframely.com/?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcodinghelp.site

Answer (score 0):

I did experience this kind of issue several times. Each time when I disable forcing all HTTP to https it starts showing images on FB again. There is some relation between http/https and images in open graph.

So there could be in general 3 places, where you can fix this:

1. Plugin (Like Really Simple SSL) could manage mixed content, so check carefully all settings related to switching between HTTP and HTTPS protocols.
2. .HTACCESS file rules. Change your htaccess file content to default from wordpress.org
3. Check your hosting or server settings that force using a secure protocol.